# Screen not showing on Mac using pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame

I'm doing a tutorial for using pygame to make games, and I'm having a problem getting a screen to show up. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pygame

# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# Create the screen, height = 800, width = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

I have pygame installed, and have no errors or warnings in PyCharm. When I run this (both in PyCharm and my terminal), I get no screen showing, and all that happens is the spaceship of the python runner is bouncing in my dock. When I run this exact code on my pc, it shows a black screen, which is the desired outcome.

Can anyone help, or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem running your code on a Mac. However, the window showing up is a grey one, not black.

In order to force the display of the window, you can add this  after the screen creation:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

And to try to figure out the problem,you may want to add a text in the window bar, that may generate a message pointing to your problem.

```
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello world")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Neither worked, so I am not sure of what to do next. My problem might be with python or pygame, as the python spaceship is bouncing in my dock, and there are no errors running the code.